# Permissions error renaming a file on disk

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I am trying to rename a file on the local hard disk from a swift MacOS application.

Basically I am bringing up the open panel to select the folder where the files are.  then I enumerate the files and rename them to the modification date.

Here is the relevant code:

```
let openPanel = NSOpenPanel()
openPanel.canChooseDirectories = true
openPanel.canChooseFiles = false
openPanel.canCreateDirectories = false
openPanel.allowsMultipleSelection = false

var mtsVideosFolderPathString : String! = ""
if openPanel.runModal() == NSApplication.ModalResponse.OK
{
    mtsVideosFolder = openPanel.urls[0] as URL
    mtsVideosFolderPathString = mtsVideosFolder?.path

    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let enumerator = fileManager.enumerator(atPath: mtsVideosFolderPathString)
    while let element = enumerator?.nextObject() as? String
    {
        if element.hasSuffix("MTS")
        {
            let filePath = "\(mtsVideosFolderPathString!)/\(element)"
            let fileModDate = self.fileModificationDate(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath))

            let format = DateFormatter()
            format.timeZone = .current
            format.dateFormat = "yyyy.MM.dd HH.mm.ss"
            let dateString = format.string(from: fileModDate!)

            let fromFilename = "\(mtsVideosFolderPathString!)/\(element)"
            let toFilename = "\(mtsVideosFolderPathString!)/\(dateString).mts"
            print("Rename \(fromFilename) to \(toFilename)")

            do {
                try fileManager.moveItem(at: URL(fileURLWithPath: fromFilename), to: URL(fileURLWithPath: toFilename))
            }
            catch let error as NSError
            {
                print("Ooops! Something went wrong: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the app its fails at moveItem in the try/catch with the following error:

```
Rename /Volumes/BigNFast/test/00000.mts to /Volumes/BigNFast/test/2013.08.05 20.09.50.mts
Ooops! Something went wrong: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=513 "“00000.mp4” couldn’t be moved because you don’t have permission to access “ test”." UserInfo={NSSourceFilePathErrorKey=/Volumes/BigNFast/test/00000.mp4, NSUserStringVariant=(
    Move
), NSDestinationFilePath=/Volumes/BigNFast/test/2013.08.05 20.09.50.mp4, NSFilePath=/Volumes/BigNFast/test/00000.mp4, NSUnderlyingError=0x6000002bb450 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"}}
```

So, the question is, how do I set the permissions?  How to I rename a file on disk?

Thank you for any help

Comment: Swift is a type inferred language. `if openPanel.runModal() == .OK {`. Btw casting a `URL` to `URL` is pointless and this will create a new DateFormatter for each file URL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Signing and Capabilities -> File Access -> User Selected File
Change it to read and write with the selector.